# Why is following code throwing runtime error, even when it shows desired output?

Tags: c, backtracking

I am solving the 8 queen problem using backtracking. When I compiled the following code in codechef IDE, it showed correct output, but still it shows runtime error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int board[8][8] = { { 0 } };
int demi[8][8] = { { 0 } };
int queen(int a, int b, int c);
void mark(int a, int b);
int main()
{
    int i;
    int b = queen(3, 0, 0);
    for (i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        int x = board[i / 8][i % 8];
        if (x == 1)
            printf(" %d ", x);
        else
        {
            printf(" 0 ");
        }
        if ((i + 1) % 8 == 0)
            printf("\n");
    }
}
int queen(int a, int b, int c)
{
    int t;
    if (c == 8)
        return 1;
    if (a < 0 || a > 7 || b < 0 || b > 7)
        return 0;
    if (!(board[a][b] == 0))
        return 0;
    for (t = 0; t < 64; t++)
    {
        demi[t / 8][t % 8] = board[t / 8][t % 8];
    }
    mark(a, b);
    board[a][b] = 1;
    /*  for(t = 2; t<8; t++)
     {
     if(queen(a+(9-t), b+1, c+1))
     return 1;
     if(queen(a-t, b+1, c+1))
     return 1;
     }*/
    if (queen(a + 7, b + 1, c + 1))
        return 1;
    if (queen(a + 6, b + 1, c + 1))
        return 1;
    if (queen(a + 5, b + 1, c + 1))
        return 1;
    if (queen(a + 4, b + 1, c + 1))
        return 1;
    if (queen(a + 3, b + 1, c + 1))
        return 1;
    if (queen(a + 2, b + 1, c + 1))
        return 1;
    if (queen(a - 2, b + 1, c + 1))
        return 1;
    if (queen(a - 3, b + 1, c + 1))
        return 1;
    if (queen(a - 4, b + 1, c + 1))
        return 1;
    if (queen(a - 5, b + 1, c + 1))
        return 1;
    if (queen(a - 6, b + 1, c + 1))
        return 1;
    if (queen(a - 7, b + 1, c + 1))
        return 1;
    board[a][b] = 0;
    for (t = 0; t < 64; t++) {
        board[t / 8][t % 8] = demi[t / 8][t % 8];
    }
    return 0;
}
void mark(int a, int b)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        int row = i / 8;
        int col = i % 8;
        if (row == a || col == b && !(row == a && col == b))
            board[row][col] = 2;
        if (abs(row - a) == abs(col - b))
            board[row][col] = 2;
    }
}
```

Output :

[image]

**Moreover, if I change the driver statement to "`queen(0,0,0) or queen(1,0,0)`", The result is well correct upto 4-5 columns, but is full of 0s in the remaining ones.**

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

just look at your main routine:

```
int main()
{
    ...
    if((i+1)%8==0)
    printf("\n");
}
```

it is supposed to return 0 on successful completion, but you don't return anything: so even if your program does what you want, since your return code is undefined.

Not likely to be 0 in that case => seen as wrong execution by the engine executing it, which doesn't even try to go further into analysing program output.

Fix (even if C99 makes it default, compiling with old C89 could yield undefined results):

```
    if((i+1)%8==0)
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

As several people commented, the `return 0` statement is not mandatory in C99. But I suppose that your on-line platform enforces strict C89 rules so you have to add it.

Comment: Thank you very much.. :)... Could you please explain the question I asked at the end?

Comment: The comment about `main()` having to explicitly return is no longer true since the 1999 standard.

Comment: You should write that it's a C89 problem. And the only way to write main is `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char **argv)`. The return value 0 is implicit since C99. Well I get no warning in C89 too.

Comment: @praveenlondhe: not sure, but that `    if (queen(a + 2, b + 1, c + 1))
        return 1;
    if (queen(a - 2, b + 1, c + 1))
        return 1;` seems to miss the +1 and -1 values. BTW you could have used a loop instead of copy/paste.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No... that was deliberate... since +1 and -1 squares are always attacked by the previously  placed queen. and thanks for the loping advice :)

Answer (score 1):

> Moreover, if I change the driver statement to "`queen(0,0,0) or queen(1,0,0)`", The result is well correct upto 4-5 columns, but is full of 0s in the remaining ones.

There's a small, but impactful oversight: The array `demi` to store the board state of a previous instance in the recursion chain of `queen()` is defined globally; hence, recursive calls of `queen()` overwrite the saved state of former invocations, foiling the backtracking. Your program works if `demi` is defined locally in `queen()`.

---

Regarding the program's exit status, the value of `b` at the end of `main()` lends itself to be used in `return !b;`, since the value 1 returned from `queen()` denotes success.